# HiveTable disappears

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have write a databse to spark ware house example tableA from spark-shell and I checked the database is there (as below)

```
+-------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|name   |description     |locationUri                                           |
+-------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|default|default database|file:/Users/Projects/data/spark-warehouse|
+-------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|dbA    |default database|file:/Users/Projects/data/spark-warehouse/dbA.db
+-------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

but when during spark-submit the databse is disapper, the path is the same anyone has idea about that? (I have use spark-shell to check the database and table are there still just not available during spark-submit)

```
+-------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|name   |description     |locationUri                                           |
+-------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|default|default database|file:/Users/Projects/data/spark-warehouse|
+-------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved by adding "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion to dependency